# How can I apply styles dynamically with ngStyle?

Tags: angular, ng-style

How can i switch left px value with right based on a boolean ?

I want to switch `[ngStyle]="{ 'left.px': offSetX }` with `[ngStyle]="{ 'right.px': offSetX }` based on a condition

```
    import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "hello",
  template: `
    <div class="myDiv" [ngStyle]="{ 'left.px': offSetX }"></div>

    <button (click)="applyRightStyle()">Apply Right Style</button>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      .myDiv {
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        margin-left: 50px;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;

  offSetX = 100;
  applyRightBoolean = false;

  applyRightStyle() {}
}
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nezurt)

Edit: I want to replace the style as in Remove the left if I apply right, and Remove Right when left is applied because `left: 0px, right: 10px` is not equal to `right: 10px`.

**Solution:** The correct way to reset `left` or `right` is to use `initial` instead of `0px`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not keep them both and reset based on a condition ?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k63eb8?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "hello",
  template: `
    <div class="myDiv" [ngStyle]="{ 'left.px': !applyRightBoolean ? offSetX : 0, 'right.px': applyRightBoolean ? offSetX : 0 }"></div>

    <button (click)="applyRightStyle()">Apply Right Style</button>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      .myDiv {
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        margin-left: 50px;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;

  offSetX = 100;
  applyRightBoolean = false;

  applyRightStyle() {
    this.applyRightBoolean = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: i didn't understand how this would work created a stackblitz of your answer https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k63eb8?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Comment: its working fine @dota2pro just add this.applyRightBoolean = true inside the function

Answer (score 4):

I think we will have to manage both styles. It would work with `ngStyle` as well but I like the `[style.xxx]` syntax:

```
@Component({
  selector: "hello",
  template: `
    <div class="myDiv" [style.left.px]="offSetLeft" [style.right.px]="offSetRight"></div>

    <button (click)="applyRightStyle()">Apply Right Style</button>
    <button (click)="applyLeftStyle()">Apply Left Style</button>

  `
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;

  offSetLeft = 100;
  offSetRight = 0;
  applyRightBoolean = false;

  applyRightStyle() {
    this.offSetLeft = 0;
    this.offSetRight = 50;
  }

  applyLeftStyle() {
    this.offSetLeft = 100;
    this.offSetRight = 0;
  }
}
```

Forked your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-woumd6?file=src/app/hello.component.ts).

Answer (score 0):

```
public bgcolor = "red";

 [style.backgroundColor]="bgcolor"
second way used like that for multiple

public bgcolor = {
    backgroundColor:"orange"
};

[ngStyle]="bgcolor"
```

for your style used like that

```
[ngStyle]="{ backgroundColor:'#' + element.color }"

<ng-container matColumnDef="color">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> color </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [ngStyle]="{ backgroundColor:'#' + element.color }" > #{{element.color}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

```
[ngStyle]="{ condition ? '\'left.px\': offSetX' : '\'right.px\': offSetX'}
```